# freezing of program, by using getimage

Tags: c++, bgi

I am using getimage and putimage to copy images from one location to another.
But the program freezes and doesn't return the control back

my code:

```
#include <graphics.h>
#include <alloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
 int gdriver = DETECT,gmode;
 initgraph(&gdriver,&gmode,"C:\\Turboc3\\BGI");

  void far *image = 0;
  int sz;

   sz = imagesize(50,50,200,200);
   image = farmalloc(sz);

    circle(100,100,50);
     getimage(50,50,200,200,image);
    while(!kbhit())
    {
      putimage(250,350,image, COPY_PUT);
      putimage(350,450,image, COPY_PUT);
       delay(10);
      putimage(250,350,image, XOR_PUT);
      }
 closegraph();
}
```

if i change this statement

```
void far *image
sz = imagesize(50,50,200,200);
   image = farmalloc(sz);
```

to this it works, can anyone tell me why this happens

```
image = (void far*) malloc((size_t)imagesize(50,50,200,200));
```

Comment: Is this not working for you also? `image = farmalloc((size_t)sz);` Remember that alloc wants unsigned int, although in this case it shouldn't matter..

Comment: yupp, its not working